# How can I create a TWRP nandroid backup without going into recovery?

Tags: backup, twrp, nandroid

I want to create a full backup.

I have TWRP installed. But the problem is, part of my screen is not working, so I can't tap on options to enable storage (photos and stuff) backup as it doesn't do that by default.

Basically, I want to tick everything on the backup options.

And I can't do it through ADB because I don't have a computer right now.

Comment: PC is required https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html